# Spark Random Forests: Different results with same seed

Tags: scala, apache-spark, machine-learning, random-forest

When running Spark's RandomForest algorithm, I seem to get different splits in the trees on different runs even when using the same seed. Could anyone kindly explain if I am doing something wrong (likely), or the implementation is buggy (which I believe to be unlikely)? Here is the scheme of my run:

```
//read data into rdd
//convert string rdd to LabeledPoint rdd
// train_LP_RDD is RDD of LabeledPoint
// call random forest
val seed = 123417
val numTrees = 10
val numClasses = 2
val categoricalFeaturesInfo: Map[Int, Int] = Map() 
val featureSubsetStrategy = "auto"
val impurity = "gini"
val maxDepth = 8
val maxBins = 10
val rfmodel = RandomForest.trainClassifier(train_LP_RDD, numClasses, categoricalFeaturesInfo,
                        numTrees, featureSubsetStrategy, impurity, maxDepth, maxBins,seed)
println(rfmodel.toDebugString)
```

On two different runs, the output of this snippet is different. For example, a diff on two results shows the following:

```
sdiff -bBWs run1.debug run2.debug

If (feature 2 <= 15.96)             |         If (feature 2 <= 16.0)
Else (feature 2 > 15.96)            |         Else (feature 2 > 16.0)
If (feature 2 <= 15.96)             |         If (feature 2 <= 16.0)
Else (feature 2 > 15.96)            |         Else (feature 2 > 16.0)
If (feature 2 <= 33.68)             |         If (feature 2 <= 34.66)
Else (feature 2 > 33.68)            |         Else (feature 2 > 34.66)
If (feature 1 <= 17.0)              |         If (feature 1 <= 16.0)
Else (feature 1 > 17.0)             |         Else (feature 1 > 16.0)
```

Comment: have you figured this out yet? if so, how? otherwise, do you have some sample data you could share to complete a minimally reproducible example?

Comment: I tried to replicate this in the latest version of Spark 3.0 . Unable to replicate. Probably this is an old version issue

Comment: This is probably caused by using featureSubsetStrategy  as "auto". This would incur some probabilistic estimation of number of features used for model generation. Could you try using a numeric value or "all". Found a good article about Randomforest  featureSubsetStrategy here - https://dzone.com/articles/classification-using-random-forest-with-spark-20. This might help.

Comment: This could also be related: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/402391/why-the-performance-of-random-forest-is-related-to-the-order-of-training-samples . The order of the input data.

Comment: I took a look at the source code for feature selection, [RandomForest.selectNodesToSplit](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/5ed89ceaf367590f79401abbf9ff7fc66507fe4e/mllib/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/ml/tree/impl/RandomForest.scala#L1043) is responsible for it. It uses a random generator that has the seed, you can check [here](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/5ed89ceaf367590f79401abbf9ff7fc66507fe4e/mllib/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/ml/tree/impl/RandomForest.scala#L168). This is at least from version 2.0 on. So feature selection does not seem to be the issue @AbdulRahman

Answer (score 1):

Can't tell without more context (and not enough rep to comment), but as Shaido suggested, one cause could be that `train_LP_RDD` is not deterministic.  E.g. if you're doing something like

```
train_LP_RDD = sc.textFile(path).sample(withReplacement=False, fraction=0.5)
```

Then you're going to get different samples each time you run `trainClassifier`, even if you're not re-defining `train_LP_RDD`.

Comment: Just realized OP hasn't been seen for 4 years... but anyway, in case anyone is coming here with a similar question, you can leave a comment/answer.

Comment: Gotta be careful answering an old question like this with somewhat of another question in place of a comment. I know you don't have the ability to comment, but regardless, in these situations, you will often get voted down upon initial review of you answer (it goes through an initial review because you are new and posting to a very very old question). No biggie, just a fair warning, you may get some downvotes.

Comment: Thanks, really appreciate your taking the time to explain!